# c# - Manually scroll Control with AutoScroll=true

Tags: c#, winforms, scroll

I have a `Panel` with `AutoScroll=true`. I'd like to manually scroll the panel's `VerticalScroll`. I've tried both setting `VerticalScroll.Value` and `Panel.ScrollControlIntoView(...)`.

However, both cases yielded the following result: The scrollbar does appear to have scrolled to the value but the panel's contents remain unmoved. Scrolling upwards shows an empty panel.

I'm trying to do this during startup. If I scroll directly to the control after a delay (from a thread), it works (though setting the scrollbar value doesn't).

Is there a better (synchronous) way of achieving what I'm looking for?

Comment: Assign the AutoScrollPosition property to force a scroll.

Comment: That doesn't seem to do anything. I've tried assigning both positive and negative values but the `AutoScrollPosition` remains `(0,0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Shown` event, for example:

```
private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.panel1.ScrollControlIntoView(this.button1);
    //Or if you need a special location:
    //this.panel1.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(100, 100);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for. Makes sense that you can't scroll before the `Form` is shown.